# JQuery - Callback for offset()/position()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, promise

I have a `div` containing a list elements, which have static positioning and for each element I want to

1. Record its absolute positioning using the `offset()` method
2. Change its positioning to `absolute`, move it somewhere else, and later move it back to its original position using the recorded coordinates

First I tried this:

```
var positions = {};
myDiv.children().each(function(){
    var child = $(this);
    var id = child.attr('id');
    var offset = child.offset();
    positions[id] = [offset.left, offset.top];

    child .css('position', 'absolute');
    var x = ...;
    var y = ...;
    child.css('left', x);
    child.css('top', y);
});

console.log(positions);
```

In this case, every entry of the 'positions' object have the same coordinates (value for the first element). However, if I comment out the bit that moves the element, the `positions` objects has the correct coordinates for each child.

So I'm guessing it's a synchronisation issue, because the `css` function is called before the `offset` function has terminated.

So what I need really, is to make sure that the block `child.css('left', x); child.css('top', y);` is only executed when the 'offset' function is done.

I tried things like

```
$.queue(child, 'foo', function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        positions[id] = [offset.left, offset.top];
        jQuery.dequeue(this);
    });
$.dequeue(child, 'foo');
child.promise().done(function() {
        child.css('position', 'absolute');
        ...
    });
```

but with no luck: when I log the `positions` objects it still has the wrong coordinates.

I am quite new to JS and JQuery so I'm sure how to do the right thing here.

How can I make sure the block `child.css('left', x); child.css('top', y);` will only be executed after the 'positions' object has been populated with the correct offset coordinates?

**EDIT**
I just realised that in my case I need to use 'position()' rather than 'offset()' but that doesn't really change the problem that I have described

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `.each()` changing sibling elements' position could be cause of getting wrong coordinates after the first one.

Why don't you get and store all positions before changing? 
I mean you should iterate childrens double times.

1. Iterate childrens and store position, don't change any css,
2. Iterate childrens again and change css.

Comment: As a hack I'm also using timers as well but was wondering if there is something cleaner. In your simple example you have only one element which also works in my case: the first child gets his coordinates stored correctly but all the other don't. They Actually get the same values as the first guy

Comment: In `.each()` changing sibling elements' position could be cause of getting wrong coordinates after the first one. Why don't you get and store all positions before changing? I mean you should iterate childrens double times. 1- iterate childrens and store position, don't change any css, 2- iterate childrens again and change css.

Comment: This is an excellent point and it explains everything! It was not a syncrhonisation issue at all, everything was working fine indeed. I tried your suggestion and it works perfectly. Please post and an answer and I'll accept it.